# sort my entity data source

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I dragged an Entity Data Source on to my asp.net web page and a gridview. How exactly do I sort my gridview by default on a column (and descending order)? I've tried a lot of things with no luck.

Thanks,

rod.

Comment: I've tried the OrderBy property of the EntityDataSource object using different expressions 'Order By DatePosted Desc', 'DatePosted Desc', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx) method of the GridView.